# My sheets add on needs form, how to package together in Add On Store?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

Thanks to folks on this site I've managed to put together an add on that does something valuable at the school where  I  teach. I spent the last three days with some folks from other schools who are interested in running the app,  so I shared a read-only copy with  them.

It relies on a form to send data to a sheet.

It makes more sense to put it in the Add On store so I can update  it. I also have plans for some in app paid solutions to extend it and pay for some of my  time (this was not in my job description and done on my own time).

Is it possible to link the form and the spreadsheet as a package in the add on store?

Comment: There is no built-in capability to link multiple add-ons together.  It is possible to do something like put an On Form Submit trigger in both a Form and a Sheet.  So when the Form was submitted, an add-on installed in both the Form and Sheet would run.  If you are talking about how an add-on is discovered in the Chrome Web Store, there is no built-in way to associate them.  You could explain in the add-on description of each add-on that it is meant to work together with another add-on and provide the Chrome Store link.

Comment: Create the form with the spreadsheet add-on, and bind its destination to be the spreadsheet with the add-on. Then programmatically create the on submit trigger. You can use spreadsheet menus to call these task-based functions.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @Sandy Good, I thought about doing that and explaining it on a page. That is a simple solution.

Comment: @tehhowch, you gave me some good search terms. And there you are helping me again. Grateful!